# Should you spend any time expressing interest in companies even when there isn't a role that is a direct match?

Tags: job-search

There are many companies that encourage you to send your resume and details out even when there isn't a direct match with the roles that they are looking to fill and your profile. 
Is there any value in spending any time drafting a response to such companies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can it be potentially useful or valuable? Yes, you can get a great job that way, especially if you have the type of skill-set that is in demand or sufficiently uncommon.

Should you spend a **large portion** of your time during a job search doing this? **No, definitely not**. Most companies who do this are in no rush to hire, which means you generally need to just get lucky or have a particularly great match to their business.

All the fine details depend on your particular experience, industry, whether the company really is in a position to hire, approach, connections in the company, etc. Contacting a company in this way is little more than cold calling. And with things like email and online resume submission, the big problem is you have little to no contact with a real person and it's easy to waste weeks of your time applying to opportunities that do not exist.

Now in some industries (especially in the past), the best way to get a job was actually calling up companies and asking for a manager, introducing you and your experience very concisely, and ask if they might be looking for someone to hire. In my first career (printing), this method got me multiple job offers within days - because I had very specific, rare experience and skills that most of the population did not have. It also helped that these were all small companies and it was easy to talk to the manager in charge of hiring for the position I was interested in.

So while there is a potential chance of getting a job, the big problem is that so much is out of your hands that there is very little way to estimate your chances of success in even a vague way. I might suggest a rule of thumb, like only spending 1/5th (or even 1/10th) of your job search resources reaching out in this way, with the rest of your time dedicated to methods more likely to result in a job.

Comment: +1 I got many of my jobs by just cold asking managers when there wasn't even a position advertised. It depends on your skillset.